# python 2.7.5+ print list without spaces after the commas

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, printing, format

I do

```
print [1,2]
```

But I want the print to output in the format [1,2] *without* the extra space after the comma.

Do I need some "stdout" function for this?`

Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2

Comment: Try str.join http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data in hand is a list of numbers. So, first we convert them to strings and then we join the join the strings with [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function and then print them in the format `[{}]` using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), here `{}` represents the actual joined string.

```
data = [1,2, 3, 4]
print(data)                                       # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print("[{}]".format(",".join(map(repr, data))))   # [1,2,3,4]

data = ['aaa','bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
print(data)                                       # ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
print("[{}]".format(",".join(map(repr, data))))   # ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']
```

If you are using strings

data = ['aaa','bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
print("[{}]".format(",".join(map(repr, data))))

Or even simpler, get the string representation of the list with [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) function and then replace all the space characters with empty strings.

```
print(repr(data).replace(" ", ""))                 # [1,2,3,4]
```

**Note:** The replace method will not work if you are dealing with strings and if the strings have space characters in them.

Comment: data = ['aaa','bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
print("[{}]".format(",".join(map(str, data))))  # [aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd]
How do I keep the quotes?

Comment: @user1614113 I updated my answer. Does this answer your question now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use repr, then remove all spaces:

```
>>> print repr([1,2]).replace(' ', '')
[1,2]
```

Make sure you have no spaces in every element.

Comment: OP wants to use strings as well. Try `["abc def"]`

Comment: Nope. Try the input as it is in my previous comment.