# Printing Values from a list without spaces in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list

Suppose I have a list like

```
list1 = ['A','B','1','2']
```

When i print it out I want the output as

```
AB12
```

And not

```
A B 1 2
```

So far I have tried

```
(a)print list1,
(b)for i in list1:
    print i,
(c)for i in list1:
    print "%s", %i
```

But none seem to work.
Can anyone suggest an alternate method
Thank you.

Comment: What about `''.join(list)`?

Comment: what about _not_ calling your list `list` ?

Comment: That too. @Jean-FrançoisFabre is right. `list` is not a good name for a list in python as `list` actually a method.

Comment: @EliSadoff thanks for commenting and _not_ answering this question. I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No worries. I've been trying to find a duplicate and I have yet to find one. I wish there was a "this is a built-in that you should know how use" or "RTFM" flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 2.7.5+ print list without spaces after the commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660588/python-2-7-5-print-list-without-spaces-after-the-commas)

Comment: @EliSadoff: found one :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nice going!

Comment: @EliSadoff     I have changed the name, thanks for pointing it out.
Sorry I didn't name it correctly in the first place. I m new to this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments on @jftuga answer, I guess that the input you provided is not the one you're testing with. You have mixed contents in your list.

My answer will fix it for you:

```
lst = ['A','B',1,2]
print("".join([str(x) for x in lst]))
```

or

```
print("".join(map(str,lst)))
```

I'm not just joining the items since not all of them are strings, but I'm converting them to strings first, all in a nice generator comprehension which causes no memory overhead.

Works for lists with only strings in them too of course (there's no overhead to convert to `str` if already a `str`, even if I believed otherwise on my first version of that answer: [Should I avoid converting to a string if a value is already a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = "".join(list1)
print(a)
```

This will give you: `AB12`

Also, since `list` is a built-in Python class, do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: This command doesnt work
I  get an error as
"TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, int found
"

Comment: @john: rename your variable to something other than `list`

Comment: @john: you have a different input list. it contains integers & strings.